# Is there a shortcut for the last used tool?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I know this question sounds really simple; I'm a beginner with Photoshop.

I'm learning about the different tools. Is there a keyboard shortcut for accessing the last used tool? If not, would it be possible with AppleScript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Um... not really, but Photoshop has another trick up its sleeve that you might like even better, and is arguably much more useful.

Every tool has a keyboard shortcut, and when you're using one tool -- say, the Brush (B) and you want to switch to another -- the Eraser (E), let's say -- you would press and hold `e`, erase what you wanted, then release the key to revert to the Brush. These "spring-loaded keys" came in somewhere around CS4, and they're a great help in speeding workflow.

Rather than trying to cook up a script, if you want to get up to speed with Photoshop, make a cheat sheet of the keyboard shortcuts and learn them. They're pretty easy (B for Brush, E for Eraser, S for clone Stamp, R for Rotate canvas etc.), and in the not-so-very-long run this will prove far more useful and versatile than an automated "last used tool".

Comment: I didn't know that, and I think it is going to come in very handy!  thank you!

Comment: is there a tag [yearslost] or should i create it?